# laravel blade : image display does not work

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-9

I want to display an image in view file.
I tried several lines of code.

This is a part of my controller

```
        $filename = time().'.'.$request->logo->extension();
        $partner->logo = $request->logo->storeAs(
            'partnerLogos',
             $filename,
            'public'
        );
```

I linked storage folder.
The file is saved in : storage/app/public/partnerLogos/1665127813.jpg

In My view file, I tried 4 different ways to display the image, it only works when I put the file name.

```
 <img src="{{ asset('storage/partnerLogos/'.$partner->logo) }}" alt="">
```

Result : http://localhost:8000/storage/partnerLogos

```
{{ asset('storage/partnerLogos/'.$partner->logo) }}
```

Result : /partnerLogos/1665127813.jpg

```
 <?php print_r($partner->logo); ?>
```

Result : partnerLogos/1665127813.jpg

```
  <img src="{{asset('storage/partnerLogos/1665127813.jpg')}}" alt="">
```

Result : image is displayed

Comment: kindly post minimal-complete code representing your issue.

Comment: "doesn't work" - what does that mean? What have oyu tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Form the given example, this looks obvious to me: if printing `$partner->logo` returns a URL ending in `5418.png`, you should not compare that to loading an image through a URL ending in `5200.png`

Comment: @Fab833 did you check $partner->logo in print_r($partner->logo)

Comment: The storage folder publically available by default. You'd have to [link it](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) before you can access it from your webroot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the images in `storage` directory, consider that you will not access them via a direct address, since It is not stored in `public` directory!

You should add images in `storage/app/public` directory and after that run

> php artisan storage:link

It creates symbol link, so the images will be accessible by asset.

for more information check this [example](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-display-image-from-storage-folder-in-laravelexample.html)